# To check a windows service state as running by running a loop upto 3 increments

Tags: powershell

Hi I have a scenario where I need to to check a windows service state as running by running a loop upto 3 increments and after every increment wait for 10 sec before incrementing the loop.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using a simple `for()` loop like this:

```
$serviceName = 'TheServiceName'
$maxTries    = 3
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxTries; $i++) {
    $status = (Get-Service -Name $serviceName).Status
    Write-Host "Service '$serviceName' status is $status"
    if ($status -eq 'Running') {
        # exit the loop
        break
    }
    # service is not running, so sleep for 10 seconds and try again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```

Make sure you test on the service `Name` or `DisplayName` property, they differ..